Cannot log to my postgres db created with docker
I'm new to docker in general but I want to setup a database with it (PSQL)
I have a simple Dockerfile:
FROM postgres:latest

ENV POSTGRES_USER docker
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD admin
ENV POSTGRES_DB docker

EXPOSE 5432

CMD ["postgres"]

then I execute the following command to create my image:
docker build -t docker_db . image gets created succesfully.
Then I start a container with the following command: docker run --name postgres  -p 5432:5432  -v ~/postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data  -d docker_db
But when I try to login to my database using the command:
psql -h localhost -U docker
`
I get the following error
Password for user docker: psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "docker"
If I use a db client like dbeaver and I try to connect with same credentials it does not work but if I try to setup a connection to a db postgres with user postgres and pwd admin it works, although I don't see my docker db.

The environment variables are only used if no database exists when the container starts. If you already have a database in ~/postgres_data, then you need to use a user and password defined in that database. To check if that's the issue, try running the container without the volume mapping. Then a fresh database will be created.

Ok you are right it works thanks. I have another question because I read on another stackoverflow topic  that using init scripts was no longer useful since July 2015. Is this true for all commands? Let's say I want to create a schema after creating my db? Do I have to add an init.sql file? If so I would just have to add it to my Dockerfile?

If you want to create a schema, you can do it by placing it in the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory in the image. But be aware that init scripts are also only run if no database exists on container startup. The image page is actually quite good at explaining how you use the image.
